# PHP - creating a new array through nested arrays while creating a post/image relationship

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

- PHP 7.2
- Wordpress 4.9.8
- Advanced Custom Fields 5.7.7

I'm interested in creating an array where each item would hold:

- post id
- post title
- array of images belonging to post

I am using an ACF repeater for every post that holds many images, the repeater name is `carousel`.

There is no connection between the WP post object and the ACF fields.

### The issue:

nested foreach pushes all the images into the first post.

### Expected:

nested foreach will fill the `$randomArray` only with images that belong to that post ID.

```
$workshop_posts_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'workshops'
);

$randomArray = [
    'post_id' => '',
    'post_title' => '',
    'post_image_url' => []
];
$post_query = new WP_Query($workshop_posts_args);
if ($post_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
        $post_query->the_post();
        $carousel_array = get_field('carousel', get_the_ID());
        echo "<h2>".get_the_title()."</h2>";
        if ($carousel_array) {
            foreach ($carousel_array as $carousel_images) {
                foreach ($carousel_images as $image) {
                    $randomArray['post_id'] = get_the_ID();
                    $randomArray['post_title'] = get_the_title();
                    $randomArray['post_image_url'][] = $image['url'];
                    echo 'image_url:'.$image['url'].'<br>The array: <pre>'.print_r($randomArray, true).'</pre>';
                    ?>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<h1>TOTAL ARRAY</h1>
<pre><?php print_r($randomArray) ?></pre>
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie this is the result: https://pastebin.com/SFZ7pZu6

Comment: i have got your problem and updated my code in answer.check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-writing array index again and again inside loop and that's you problem.

so do:-

```
$randomArray = []; //before post_query
```

And change `if` block like below:-

```
if ($post_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
        $post_query->the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $randomArray[$id]['post_id'] = $id;
        $randomArray[$id]['post_title'] = get_the_title();
        $carousel_array = get_field('carousel', $id);
        if ($carousel_array) {
            foreach ($carousel_array as $carousel_images) {
                foreach ($carousel_images as $image) {
                    $randomArray[$id]['post_image_url'][] = $image['url'];
                    ?>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note:- rest code will be same

the above code will give you `post-id` based multi-dimensional array. if you want indexes to be 0,1,2,3..... format then do:-

```
$randomArray = array_values($randomArray);
```

Comment: perfect. Now I know better how to treat these arrays, thanks !

Comment: @clusterBuddy  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Use proper indexing of `$randomArray` like below:

```
<?php
  $workshop_posts_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'workshops'
);

$randomArray = array();
$post_query = new WP_Query($workshop_posts_args);
$index = 0;
if ($post_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
        $post_query->the_post();
        $randomArray[$index]['post_id'] = get_the_ID();
        $randomArray[$index]['post_title'] = get_the_title();
        $carousel_array = get_field('carousel', get_the_ID());
       //echo "<h2>".get_the_title()."</h2>";
       if ($carousel_array) {
        foreach ($carousel_array as $carousel_images) {
            foreach ($carousel_images as $image) {

                $randomArray[$index]['post_image_url'][] = $image['url'];
                //echo 'image_url:'.$image['url'].'<br>The array: <pre>'.print_r($randomArray, true).'</pre>';
                ?>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
    $index++;
}
}
?>
<h1>TOTAL ARRAY</h1>
<pre><?php print_r($randomArray) ?></pre>
```